# else not working after nested if else fails

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing some conditional concatenations on pairs of strings. if the condition is not satisfied, then a space should be added between the two
The following is a small subset of my larger code but replicates my problem

```
a = "ai";
b = "b";
res = "";
if (a.match(/ai$/)) 
          {
            if (b.match(/^ā/) || b.match(/^a/) ||
                b.match(/^i/) || b.match(/^ī/) ||
                b.match(/^u/) || b.match(/^ū/) ||
                b.match(/^e/) || b.match(/^o/) ||
                b.match(/^ṛ/))
                {
                  res = a.slice(0, -1) + 'a ' + b
                }
          }
else
   res = a+ ' ' + b
```

the result should be `ai b`
But I get ''

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That else clause is not for the nested if, it is for the outer if. Also, your indentation and inconsistent bracket usage makes your code hard to read.

Comment: `a.match(/ai$/)` returns `true`, there is no reason for the `else` branch of the outer `if` to execute.

Comment: Better formatting would help show why it would fail when the seond if is not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `else` inside the first `if` so that that `else` is triggered when the inner `if` is not satisfied:

```js
a = "ai";
b = "b";
res = "";
if (a.match(/ai$/)) 
{
  if (b.match(/^ā/) || b.match(/^a/) ||
      b.match(/^i/) || b.match(/^ī/) ||
      b.match(/^u/) || b.match(/^ū/) ||
      b.match(/^e/) || b.match(/^o/) ||
      b.match(/^ṛ/))
      {
        res = a.slice(0, -1) + 'a ' + b
      }
      else{
        res = a+ ' ' + b
      }

}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested if doesn't go to the outer else for example:

```
if (1 === 1) {
    if (1 === 2) {
       console.log(1);
    }
}
else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

the else statement in this case will never trigger.

It seems to me that what you need to do is simply combine the if statements:

```
a = "ai";
b = "b";
res = "";
if (a.match(/ai$/) && (b.match(/^ā/) || b.match(/^a/) ||
                b.match(/^i/) || b.match(/^ī/) ||
                b.match(/^u/) || b.match(/^ū/) ||
                b.match(/^e/) || b.match(/^o/) ||
                b.match(/^ṛ/))) {
    res = a.slice(0, -1) + 'a ' + b;
}
else {
   res = a + ' ' + b;
}
```

note the extra "(" after the && this is so the entire statement is treated as one unit and not seperated.